# Post JSON-Data from PlayFramework form

Tags: java, javascript, json, playframework, playframework-2.3

Play Framework provides a way to access JSON-Data in a request-body via `request().body().asJson()`. Using form-helpers does not post data in JSON-format.

So, what is the best way, in a play-application, to convert the form-data to a json-object **before** passing it to the controller?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need json in controller? Or would POJO be ok?

Comment: Did you look at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaJsonActions

Comment: yes but this only applies to controller-code. What I need is a way to send JSON from the client to the controller

Comment: But *why* do you want JSON?

Comment: because I like to send the request directly to my REST API which supports JSON

Comment: Why not keep things simple and use a plain HTML form and use a body parser of type url-encoded and then do Json.toJson(request.body())?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**1.Serialize the form to a JSON-Object**

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function(){
var o = {};
var a = this.serializeArray();
$.each(a, function() {
    if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
        if (!o[this.name].push) {
            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
        }
        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    } else {
        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
});
return o;
};
```

**2.Define an AJAX request with content type `application/json`**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" 
});

function request(path, params, method) {
method = method || "POST";

$.ajax({
    url: path,
    type: method,
    data: params,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {
        //do something
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        //do something
    }
});
}
```

**3.Send data after form submission**

```
$(function() {
var url = "/api/route";

$('form').submit(function() {
    var json = JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject());
    request(url, json);
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: See, it wasn't that hard(that serialization to get a JSON though... ). You're cheating by reproviding a given solution but who cares as long as you made it.

Comment: I was hoping for an answer like this. Now I hope that it might help someone else :) Thanks for your time though

Answer (score -1):

When you retrieve request payload data you can use either `BodyParsers`(they use the `Content-Type` header to parse the payload into something else) or you can get the payload yourself via form binding or directly as JSON ***IF*** you have a JSON/textual payload in the request body.

In your case, you have a `Content-Type` of either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ***OR*** `multipart/form-data`. So you need to bind to that form with a helper class get that data and IF you really want to convert it to JSON you'll just add an additional step of inserting it in a ObjectNode.

If you want your form data as JSON, do the conversion directly on the frontend, if possible and send it in the body as `Content-Type application/json`.

Now, do you understand why what you want to do just adds additional complexity for no apparent gain?

Comment: I really like negative votes without explanations... bring them on, wise ones!

Comment: I know this. In fact, that was my question.

Comment: And I was giving you the arguments why it's not a good idea. That's all.

Comment: Plus, if you read the third paragraph you'll see the answer to "what is the best way in a play-application to convert the form-data to a json-object before passing it to the controller?". Well, partially, because it's not in the play-app...

Comment: I was not asking for arguments against this approach but for a solution.

Comment: In my answer you have 2, mate(second and third paragraph).

Comment: that is imo the repetition of my question